# Why there is asymmetry in rxJs api

Tags: rxjs

This is maybe question more bout philosophy but for me important. Maybe one of you understand the source of this strange (at least for me) design. So in rxjs we have `Observable` and we have `Subject`. Subjects are in fact Observables on steroids but there are also extra features that you can add to Subject . You can use `ReplySubject` you can use `AsyncSubject` but you can't `ReplyObservable`. Is there any good reason for this? Of course you can go with operators, but api is still at least strange.

Answer (score 0):

Subjects are both observables and observers. They're often the easiest way to transition from any imperative/object-oriented approach into functional/reactive streams (observables).

They're also one of the fairly standard ways to multicast a stream (Many of the multicasting operators actually use a subject internally to do their work).

#### Imperative to Reactive:

For example:

Ideologically, a BehaviorSubject represents a property. You can use its `.next` and `.value` as direct replacements for setting and getting a property's value. More importantly, however, you can react to changes in that value as though it were part of an observable stream (because Subjects are observables).

#### Why aren't there BehaviorObservables?

In some ways, this exists and in others, it doesn't. An observable can be given most of these behaviors with various operators.

```
const behaviourStream$ = stream$.pipe(
  startWith(defaultValue),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Every operator (at least pipeable) operator functions over Observables. They transform an observable from one type to another (often by implicitly manipulating the values within).

What properties an observable has depends on how it has been transformed. It's not often all that helpful to have specialized observables the same way it's helpful to have specialized Subjects.

Instead, observables have static operators that create new observables with certain built-in characteristics.

These are creation operators like `interval`, `timer`, `from`, etc

Answer (score 0):

That is said. Subject has status, Observable don't, Observable is just like pure function, grab input, return output, end of story. Subject could store input one or other way, which makes it more rich and flexible